Block diagonalization of hermitian matrix composed of blocks
Suppose I have the following hermitian matrix
$$
C=\begin{pmatrix}A & B \newline B^\dagger & O\end{pmatrix}
$$
where $A$ is a hermitian $M\times M$ matrix, $B$ a $M\times N$ matrix and $O$ a $N\times N$ matrix of zeros. Is the any unitary transformation of the form $U^\dagger C U$ that can convert this matrix into a block diagonal matrix?

What does $\dagger$ represent?

Assuming $\dagger$ refers to the conjugate transpose, $C$ is Hermitian, so there is a unitary $U$ such that $U^\dagger C U$ is diagonal.
